# Logstash sometimes duplicately populating fields when using multiline filter?

Tags: logstash

The issue I have seems to be similar to https://logstash.jira.com/browse/LOGSTASH-1892, but I'm running on Logstash-shipper 1.4.2 and this page claims the issue was fixed in 1.4.1.

See a screenshot here:
[image: Valid XHTML].